# Linux desktop freezes after sleep

Tags: linux-mint, freeze

I'm new to linux and I've been running into some trouble. I use linux mint and sometimes (fairly often) after my laptop goes to sleep it freezes completely when it wakes up. I can't move the mouse, click, use the keyboard, or open a terminal. The only way I can get out of it is to force shutdown. I've used several different distros and they all have this problem. Is there any kind of fix to this or should I just go back to windows?

Laptop model: Toshiba Satellite S50D-A

Mint version: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

inxi -Fxzc0 output:

```
System:    Host: jack-pc Kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
       Desktop: Cinnamon 3.2.6 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1)
       Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Machine:   System: TOSHIBA (portable) product: Satellite S50D-A v: PSKKWC-00G005
       Mobo: AMD model: VG10AD Bios: Insyde v: 1.30 date: 11/05/2013
CPU:       Quad core AMD A10-5745M APU with Radeon HD Graphics (-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
       flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm)    bmips: 16769
       clock speeds: max: 2100 MHz 1: 1500 MHz 2: 1800 MHz 3: 2100 MHz
       4: 1500 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8610G]
       bus-ID: 00:01.0
       Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M]
       bus-ID: 01:00.0
       Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
       Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
       GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
       GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller
       driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:14.2
       Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
       driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:01.1
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-53-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       driver: rtl8188ee port: 3000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
       IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
       Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet
       driver: alx port: 2000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
       IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (2.7% used)
       ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD5000BPVX size: 500.1GB temp: 26C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 452G used: 5.9G (2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
       ID-2: swap-1 size: 7.73GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 36.1C mobo: N/A gpu: 33.0,N/A
       Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 269 Uptime: 11:51 Memory: 909.9/7178.3MB
       Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
       Client: Shell (bash 4.3.461) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: You mention laptop and sleep. Can you add your laptop model, Mint version, and `inxi -Fxzc0` output to your question?

Comment: You cannot move the mouse. Therefore after the laptop wakes, you see the X11 GUI but you cannot manipulate it. What happens if you try to kill X (on systems I have used it was Ctrl Alt backspace or Ctrl Shift backspace, you may have to enable it first), or use Ctrl Alt F2 to go to a virtual terminal, or execute the first few commands from the Magic SysRq REISUB combination -- Alt SysRq R, Alt SysRq E, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using xkill, or if your keyboard works then press Ctrl+Alt+F2, which will take you to command line inteface. There type *top* command and check which processes are utilizing most of the cpu and memory. Kill those processes by pressing K and then the PID of the process. 
To go back to GUI, type startx and press enter.